# How to calculate duration from a "start - end" string more succinctly

Tags: r, lubridate, duration

I have times stamps indicating the time an event started and the time it ended:

```
x <- "00:01:00.000 - 00:01:10.500"
```

I need to calculate the event's duration. Using `hms`from the package `lubridate`as well as `lapply` and `strsplit`does give me the expected output:

```
library(lubridate)
unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, split=" - "), function(x) as.numeric(hms(x))))[2] - unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, split=" - "), function(x) as.numeric(hms(x))))[1] 
[1] 10.5
```

But I feel the code is utterly inelegant and anything but succinct. Is there any better way to get the duration?

**EDIT**:

What if, as *is* indeed the case, there are many more than just one value in `x`, such as:

```
x <- c("00:01:00.000 - 00:01:10.500", "00:12:12.000 - 00:13:10.500")
```

I've come up with this solution:

```
timepoints <- lapply(strsplit(x, split=" - "), function(x) as.numeric(hms(x)))
duration <- lapply(timepoints, function(x) x[2]-x[1])

duration
[[1]]
[1] 10.5

[[2]]
[1] 58.5
```

But, again, there's surely a nicer and shorter one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way :

```
as.numeric(diff(lubridate::hms(strsplit(x, split=" - ")[[1]])))
#[1] 10.5
```

Keeping it in base R :

```
as.numeric(diff(as.POSIXct(strsplit(x, split=" - ")[[1]], format = '%H:%M:%OS')))
#[1] 10.5
```

---

For multiple values, we can use `sapply` :

```
library(lubridate)
sapply(strsplit(x, " - "), function(y) diff(period_to_seconds(hms(y))))

#[1] 10.5 80.5
```

and in base R :

```
sapply(strsplit(x, " - "), function(y) {
   x1 <- as.POSIXct(y, format = '%H:%M:%OS')
   difftime(x1[2], x1[1], units = "secs")
})
```

Comment: How would this have to be adjusted to work on several timestamps, e.g., `x <- c("00:01:00.000 - 00:01:10.500", "00:01:00.000 - 00:02:20.500")`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann See updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `x` can be a character vector, read it into a data frame using `read.table` and then convert the relevant columns to hms, take their difference and convert to numeric giving the vector shown.  You might need the `as.is=TRUE` argument to `read,table` if you are using a version of R prior to 4.0.

```
library(lubridate)

# test input
x <- c("00:01:00.000 - 00:01:10.500", "00:01:00.000 - 00:01:10.500")

with(read.table(text = x), as.numeric(hms(V3) - hms(V1)))
## [1] 10.5 10.5
```

or using magrittr and the same input `x` as above:

```
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

x %>%
  read.table(text = .) %$% 
  as.numeric(hms(V3) - hms(V1))
## [1] 10.5 10.5
```